# How to find whether update deployment successfully completed in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am using kubernetes api to deploy deployment in node. I got 200 status when i update the image of deployment. But the image name is wrong so deployment update stopped with errImagePull error. Is there any error callback mechanism in kubernetes or i have to debug it manually?

Comment: [K8s watch api](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#watch) is a good choice, it will return pod event if the status changed, you can react to these changes. For kubectl is: `kubectl get pod -w -n ns|grep you-pod `

Comment: @Ray how can we find new pod name when we update deployment

Comment: You can use `labelSelector` to select that pod, `request.addQueryParam("labelSelector", your-labelSelector);`. For kubectl: `kubectl get po -n your-namespace -l k=v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part you have to debug it manually, and things run asynchronously; but you have a couple of things you can watch.

[A Deployment's `status` field](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#deploymentstatus-v1-apps) has data about how many pods it controls are in what state.  The easy thing to check is that all of the replica counts match up, though this isn't 100%.  The slightly trickier thing to check is the [deployment status](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#deployment-status); some status combinations are listed in that documentation.

The other thing you can do is get the pod selector of the deployment, and then [list](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#list-pod-v1-core) (or, better for this case, [watch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes)) the pods that match that.  In your particular case, if any pods are in `ErrImagePull` state, that's a clear sign something is wrong.

The one vagueness here, and the thing that leads to an unclear solution, is `CrashLoopBackOff` state.  Say you're starting an application container and a database container.  The application container tries to connect to the database on startup, and if it fails, immediately exits.  Also say the database takes 60-120 seconds to start up.  Kubernetes will start both at the same time.  Since the database isn't ready, the application will exit; after retrying this a couple of times, the pod goes into `CrashLoopBackOff` *and this is normal*.  After the database starts up, the application will start successfully too.

I don't think there's a good way to distinguish the different `CrashLoopBackOff` states of "a dependency isn't ready yet", "a dependency will never be ready because of a misconfiguration", and "the code is just buggy".  When I've done this before I've used heuristics like a timeout to say, if nothing has made any forward progress in 5 minutes and the deployment isn't 100% ready yet, then it must have failed.  That's a little unsatisfying, though.

Comment: is there any way to find in which deployment generation a pod has been created. let say if i have pod with name pod-123 is there any way to find in which deployment generation number this pod (pod-123) is created.

Comment: a better approach would be, and this is a kubernetes recommendation, to have your services not crash because another service is down. In your example, your application should not go into a CrashLoopBackoff, but wait until the database is available. Check https://learnk8s.io/production-best-practices for another explanation